# "Non riesco a capire quando" / "Non so quando" + congiuntivo o indicativo?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Nelle mie domande ho usato molte volte costrutti come "non riesco a capire quando",  "non so quando", "non riesco a capire quali", ecc. Quando pongo queste domande ho sempre il dubbio se dopo si debba usare il congiuntivo o l'indicativo. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A queste espressioni segue una proposizione subordinata interrogativa indiretta, che generalmente ammette sia il congiuntivo che l'indicativo, per citare il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-indirette_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/):

> In linea generale, un’interrogativa indiretta dipendente da uno dei
>   verbi, nomi o aggettivi che rientrano nei gruppi elencati in
>   precedenza ammette sia l’indicativo sia il congiuntivo, con le
>   seguenti precisazioni:
>   (a) se è retta dal presente indicativo del verbo sapere nella forma
>   affermativa, l’interrogativa indiretta ha il verbo all’indicativo; 
>  (b)
>   se il presente di sapere è alla forma negativa, se sapere è al
>   passato, se l’interrogativa indiretta precede la frase reggente per
>   ragioni di messa in evidenza, possono aversi sia l’indicativo sia il
>   congiuntivo; 
> (c) se è retta da una forma del verbo dire,
>   l’interrogativa indiretta ha sempre l’indicativo, a meno che non sia
>   anteposta alla reggente per ragioni di messa in evidenza, nel qual
>   caso può avere anche il congiuntivo;
>  (d) se è retta da un verbo di
>   percezione in forma affermativa, l’interrogativa indiretta ha sempre
>   l’indicativo, a meno che essa non sia anteposta alla reggente per
>   ragioni di messa in evidenza, nel qual caso può avere anche il
>   congiuntivo.

In ogni caso, tengo a precisare che personalmente sento (e leggo) spesso formulazioni che non rispettano le eccezioni sopra indicate.

Comment: Dunque, con "non so" si può usare sia l'indicativo che il congiuntivo; ma con "non riesco a capire" si dovrebbe usare l'indicativo?

Comment: @Charo anche dopo "non riesco a capire" c'è un'interrogativa indiretta, quindi anche in questo caso si può utilizzare sia indicativo che congiuntivo

Comment: Verissimo: molto spesso il congiuntivo viene sbagliato anche da persone che dovrebbero conoscere la lingia italiana molto bene. http://cortmic.myblog.it/il-congiuntivo-e-morto/

Comment: @Stubborn: Lo dico per il punto (d): se è retta da un verbo di percezione in forma affermativa, ...

Comment: @Charo personalmente non classifico "riuscire" (che regge l'interrogativa indiretta) come verbo di percezione, in ogni caso in "non riesco" è in forma negativa, quindi non dovrebbe rientrare nella categoria del punto (d)